# Selecting variables for random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I made a representation of a random forest tree in `reprtree` but I have too much nodes I think:

[image: Random Forest tree I have]

The line I wrote : `RFM = randomForest(Rating ~., data = training)`

I would like to take off some variables which are not relevant, but everything I write does not work; I tried :

`RFM = randomForest(Customer_type, Rating, cogs, data = training)` to have only those three variables but I still have an error.

Do you know how could I 'select' my variables in the dataframe without writing `Rating ~.` formula? I tried to change `ntree` but I still have too much nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randomForest` accepts a formula object. Try :

```
RFM = randomForest(Rating~Customer_type + Rating + cogs, data = training)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could investigate the variable importance of all variables. If you want to exclude irrelevant variables, you could remove the variables with a negative or marginal variable importance.

I think you can simply investigate the variable importance by using: `importance(RFM)`